# Aggregate within an aggregate

Tags: sql-server, aggregates

I am trying to use multiple aggregates in a single select statement and am stuck on the one that's value is based off of another aggregate (Total revenue which is calculated by multiplying `COUNT(TrackID)` by `Unit Price`).

I am not allowed to do CTEs and have failed trying to use sub-queries. The three commented out lines are my failed attempts (not failed attempts at sub-queries, I deleted those already).

```
SELECT C.Country
    ,Ar.Name AS 'Artist Name'
    ,COUNT(T.TrackId) AS 'Track Count'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT T.Name) AS 'Unique Track Count'
    ,COUNT(T.TrackID) - COUNT(DISTINCT T.Name) AS 'Count Difference'
    --,POWER(IL.UnitPrice,COUNT(T.TrackId)) AS 'Test'
    --,SUM(IL.UnitPrice * COUNT(T.TrackID)) AS 'Total Revenue'
    --,IL.UnitPrice * COUNT(T.TrackID) AS 'Total Revenue'
    ,CASE MediaTypeId
        WHEN 3
        THEN 'Video'
        ELSE 'Audio'
        END AS MediaType
FROM Artist Ar
JOIN Album Al
    ON Al.ArtistId = Ar.ArtistId
JOIN Track T 
    ON T.AlbumId = Al.AlbumId
JOIN InvoiceLine Il
    ON Il.TrackId = T.TrackId
JOIN Invoice I
    ON I.InvoiceId = Il.InvoiceId
JOIN Customer C
    ON C.CustomerId = I.CustomerId
GROUP BY Ar.Name
    ,C.Country
    ,CASE MediaTypeId
        WHEN 3
        THEN 'Video'
        ELSE 'Audio'
        END
ORDER BY C.Country ASC, COUNT(T.TrackID) DESC, Ar.Name ASC
```

I also tried this but results get left out

```
SELECT C.Country
    ,Ar.Name AS 'Artist Name'
    ,COUNT(T.TrackId) AS 'Track Count'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT T.Name) AS 'Unique Track Count'
    ,COUNT(T.TrackId) - COUNT(DISTINCT T.Name) AS 'Count Difference'
    ,CASE MediaTypeId
        WHEN 3
        THEN 'Video'
        ELSE 'Audio'
        END AS MediaType
    ,T2.TotalRevenue
FROM Artist Ar
JOIN Album Al
    ON Al.ArtistId = Ar.ArtistId
JOIN Track T
    ON T.AlbumId = Al.AlbumId
JOIN InvoiceLine Il
    ON T.TrackId = Il.TrackId
JOIN Invoice I
    ON I.InvoiceId = Il.InvoiceId
JOIN Customer C
    ON C.CustomerId = I.CustomerId
JOIN (SELECT T.TrackId, SUM(Il.TrackId * Il.UnitPrice) AS 'TotalRevenue'
    FROM Track T
    JOIN InvoiceLine Il 
        ON T.TrackId = Il.InvoiceId
        GROUP BY T.TrackId) T2 ON T.TrackId = T2.TrackId
GROUP BY C.Country
    ,Ar.Name
    ,CASE MediaTypeId
        WHEN 3
        THEN 'Video'
        ELSE 'Audio'
        END
    ,T2.TotalRevenue
ORDER BY C.Country ASC, COUNT(T.TrackID) DESC, Ar.Name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do use aggregate in computation or aggregate within an aggregate in the same query, you need to wrap your query as inner query and use aggregate for computation in the outer query like this -

```
Select [columnsNames], [aggregates]
From
(
Your Inner Query
)a
Group By [columnsNames]
Order By [columnsNames]
```